# How can Apply multiple coupon codes in one order in magento 2.1?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.1.0

I am trying by setting `yes` to `Discard subsequent rule` it is not helping!

Comment: Did you check if `Discard subsequent rules` is turned on on all `Card Price Rules`?

Comment: Yes I have checked

Comment: @supriyamishra, This is not a standard feature of Magento 2.

Comment: MageAnts have created [multiple coupons](https://www.mageants.com/multiple-coupons-for-magento-2.html) code extension for magento 2 and it will support with latest version